# Username is split when picking the data type Person or group allow multiple selection

Tags: sharepoint-designer, workflow, designer-workflow, people-picker

When picking the data type option in Info path: person or group(allow multiple selections) it looks OK and the names are good in the Info path form.

[image]

But When the Workflow is working and try to send the mail, it split the username(see below mail pic) and due to that, the mail isn't sending to the relevant users. Is there a way to fix the issue?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**In your workflow**, In your `Send an Email action` Make sure that

- You have selected `Workflow Lookup for Users` > CLick Add.
- From the current Item > Select Your `People and Group` field.
- In `Return Field as`, Make sure you have selected `Email Addresses, Semicolon delimited`.

[image]